# Как создать очередь из записей на джанго?

Tags: python, django

В общем когда я экспереминтировал с возможностями Django у меня возник вопрос каким образом я моггу добавить очередь для записей моделей, например у меня есть пару блоков и мне нужно что бы на первом блоке у меня выводилась модель которая была зарегистрированна первой а на втором блоке должна выводится следующая запись. Каким образом я могу это сделать ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот пример query_set

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'article/sale.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

    def get_queryset(self):
    return Goods.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:1]
```

когда я редактирую код так

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'article/sale.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'

    def good(request):
        queryset = Goods.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={'queryset': queryset})
```

В html я вывожу запись так

```html
  {% for good in queryset %}
        <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price2_text }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

в итоге вот что показывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')


description1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image1_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')


description2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image2_sale = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='images/')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')



def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text


def __str__(self):
    return self.description1_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price1_text


def __str__(self):
    return self.description2_text
```

вот код блока:

```html
     {% for good in queryset %}
    <img class="image" src="{{good.image2_sale.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
      {% for good in queryset %}
        <h1 class="description">{{ good.description2_text }}</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  {% for good in queryset %}
        <h1 class="price" >{{ good.price2_text }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

но с этим кодом вообще ничего не показывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно достать все записи этой модели из базы:

```
queryset = Products.objects.all()
```

Передайте queryset в функции которая переносит вас на нужную страницу. Например:

```
def some_html_page_view(request):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'your_html_template_path', context={'queryset': queryset})
```

С помощью context мы можем передавать свои данные на страницу.
Переопределите вашу модель следующим образом:

```
class Products(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   description = models.TextField()
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
   price = models.IntegerField()
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

Вы создали модель по которой будут создаваться объекты. Вы можете создать сколько угодно объектов, не нужно каждый раз для этого обновлять модель и вносить новые поля. Код html должен выглядеть так:

```
some html code
....
<div>
    {% for object in queryset %}
  
    <h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
    <div>
        <img src='path_to_your_image/{{ object.image }}'></img>
        <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
        {{ object.price }}
    </div>
                 
    {% endfor %}
</div>

....
```

Для получения более детальной информации советую почитать [документацию
по языку шаблонов django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/)

Comment: Через точку можно обращаться к полям объекта

Comment: Если у объекта есть поле name, к нему можно обратиться через точку

Comment: Скорее всего вы немного не поняли суть вопроса, либо я не понял суть ответа, либо я неправильно применяю, как бы ту не было в вопросе я добавил что происходит когда я добавляю вашу часть кода

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста html код этого блока если он у вас есть (без джанговского синтаксиса) и код модели

Comment: вот я добавил, можете пересмотреть

Comment: ответ обновлён.

Comment: теперь блок пустой, для сведений имя модели я никоим образом не менял

Comment: в общем я более не менее разобрался но немного не в том. Так вот теперь у меня на блоках применяются только последние записи модели, но проблема в том что они применяются на всех блоках, а мне нужно чтобы на ондном одна запись а на другом последняя